# Facebook recommendation box in iframe: url is not valid

Tags: facebook

I am creating Facebook recommendation box [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/).
The domain is "http://www.mydomain.co.il/". For example("http://www.sport5.co.il/")
I can see the proper box to my right, but when I click "Get Code" and choose "IFRAME" I get this message: "A valid url is required when using the iframe implementation."
You can also try it.
What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm getting this too. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It still didn't work so I built the iframe tag myself:

```
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?  
       site=mydomain.co.il&width=300&height=300&header=  
       false&colorscheme=light&locale=he_IL"   
       scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying to build it manually too but I couldnt find the format.

Answer (score 2):

You can you use this format to creating Facebook recommendation box

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 400px; width: 236px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations.php?action=like&appId=123456789&border_color=%23ececec&font=tahoma&header=true&height=400&linktarget=_blank&locale=en_US&site=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com&width=236"></iframe>
```